# Turbolinks and Nielsen javascript tag

Tags: javascript, turbolinks

my website has Turbolinks.
I need to inject a javascript TAG from Nielsen.
This is the code

```
<script>
!function(t,n){t[n]=t[n]||{nlsQ:function(e,o,c,r,s,i){return s=t.document,r=s.createElement("script"),r.async=1,r.src=("http:"===t.location.protocol?"http:":"https:")+"//cdn-gl.imrworldwide.com/conf/"+e+".js#name="+o+"&ns="+n,i=s.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(r,i),t[n][o]=t[n][o]||{g:c||{},ggPM:function(e,c,r,s,i){(t[n][o].q=t[n][o].q||[]).push([e,c,r,s,i])}},t[n][o]}}}(window,"NOLBUNDLE");

  var nSdkInstance = NOLBUNDLE.nlsQ("P38E2BEBD-E82F-4F94-9BA9-1A4EC618F5AF","nlsnInstance");

  var nielsenMetadata = {
    type: 'static',
    assetid: "<%=hashed_url(url_for(only_path: true))%>",
    section: 'D_BRW'
    };

  nSdkInstance.ggPM("staticstart", nielsenMetadata);
</script>
```

Basically the response from Nielsen is that tag is not implemented in the right way because when I change section of my website the instance is initialized again.
I think the issue are Turbolinks but I cannot disable them...

Any hint?